# Advertising on Web Mobile Apps (like AdMob)

Tags: web-applications, jquery-mobile, admob, mobile-application

I have been using AdMob adverts on my Web Apps for a while now and I was wondering if there are other alternatives to AdMob for adding adverts to web apps.

Is AdMob the only provider of smart phone web mobile app adverts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- http://adfonic.com
- http://inmobi.com
- http://mojiva.com
- http://jumptap.com
- http://millennialmedia.com